# String can be assigned to undefined, but not object property

Tags: javascript-objects

Using NodeJS and MongoDB.

I have a mongo query and I am trying to assigned some of the properties of my query to an existing Object, which was the result of a previous query.

I am getting "TypeError: Cannot set property 'property1' of undefined"

```
enter code here

   for(var i=0; i<data.data.length; i++){
      if(data.data[i].a){
        var c = data.data[i].a.toString();
        SOMETHING.METHOD(c, function(user){
          console.log(JSON.stringify(user, null, 2));
          data.data[i].property1 = user.property1;
          data.data[i].property2 = user.property2;
          data.data[i].property3 = user.property3;

        });
      }else{
          data.data[i].property1 = "not available";
          data.data[i].property2 = "not available";
          data.data[i].property3 = "not available";
      }
```

strange thing though, is that when I assign "not available" to property1, there is no error. I have tried changing user.property1 toString() and that didn't solve it. Not sure why one assignment works and the other does not.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. A classic newb nodejs mistake. Since its asynchronous, the loop was finished before the DB query returned the results, so by the time that part of the function ran, there was no more loop to append the values to.